# Would this citrus fertilizer be suitable for chili peppers?

Tags: fertilizer, chili

I bought a bottle of organic fertilizer which is in liquid form. The instructions are in German but the merchant here labeled it as "organic fertilizer for fruit" so I just bought it.

Now I found out that it is specifically for citrus plants.  I wonder if it is still suitable for my chili pepper.

Any ideas?

> [Liquid Fertilizer for Citrus Plants](http://www.international.compo.com/en/consumer/blumenpflege/compo.html)
>
> NPK-fertilizer 7+3+6 + trace
>   elements
>
> Mediterranean plants have a special nutrient demand. This liquid
>   fertilizer covers this need and is recommended for all kinds of citrus
>   plants. The trace elements support the development of blossoms and
>   fruits, the added iron acts preventively against chlorosis.

Comment: I think this will probably not work...I've search the internet and found chili pepper don't need much nitrogen and too much nitrogen can kill them. They said the best ratio is 5:10:10.

Comment: care to make that comment an answer?

Comment: Well I am not sure and not an expert. The information is scattered over the internet.....

Answer (score 2):

You could try and check this one: http://www.eurohydro.com/publications/publications/GENERAL%20INFORMATION/GB/CHART-GB-FS-ttes%20plantes.pdf

Especially the pepper plants. However it seems that high nitrogen content with higher kalium content with low phosphorous content would be beneficial.

This would suggest that your citrus fertilizer has too low kalium contents and most likely a tad too high phosphorous content.